# I know how Merge Sort works, but How Merge Sort Code Works?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, pseudocode

You can read this on Wikipedia:

```
function merge_sort(list m)
// Base case. A list of zero or one elements is sorted, by definition.
if length(m) <= 1
    return m

// Recursive case. First, *divide* the list into equal-sized sublists.
var list left, right
var integer middle = length(m) / 2
for each x in m before middle
     add x to left
for each x in m after or equal middle
     add x to right

// Recursively sort both sublists
left = merge_sort(left)
right = merge_sort(right)

// Then merge the now-sorted sublists.
return merge(left, right)
```

On line 1 there's a list of numbers, let's say 9 6 3 7 5 1 8 2

They say that merge_sort divides the list on 2 and 2 again and again until each list has only 1 integer left, like this one:

```
9 6 3 7 5 1 8 2 -->
9 6 3 7 - 5 1 8 2 -->
9 6 - 3 7 - 5 1 - 8 2 -->
9 - 6 - 3 - 7 - 5 - 1 - 8 - 2
```

And then the numbers are put together like this:

```
6 9 - 3 7 - 1 5 - 2 8 -->
3 6 7 9 - 1 2 5 8 -->
1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 -->
```

**But I don't see where in the code the list of integers are divided on 2 again and again until each has only 1 integer left?**

```
var list left, right
var integer middle = length(m) / 2
for each x in m before middle
     add x to left
for each x in m after or equal middle
     add x to right
```

As I understand, on the code above, the list of numbers is divided to two different lists:
9 6 3 7  and  5 1 8 2

**What then happens on the code below?**

```
left = merge_sort(left)
right = merge_sort(right)
```

**Can someone explain me how the merge_sort code above exactly works step by step?**

Comment: Those are recursive calls to `merge_sort`. This is where the repeated division of lists is taking place. Each time `merge_sort` is called, a smaller list is passed to it.

Comment: Merge sort merges two *sorted* lists. So before merging, you'll have to split and (merge)sort both halves.

Comment: @joop - There's no need to recursively split a list. The method in hp / microsoft std::list::sort uses an array of pointers to the first nodes of a list, where array[i] points to a list with pow(2,i) elements, or it's NULL. Nodes are removed from the list one at a time and merged into the array, then when all nodes are merged into the array, the lists in the array are merged to form a single sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't see where in the code the list of integers are divided on 2 again and again until each has only 1 integer left?

```
var list left, right
var integer middle = length(m) / 2          --------statement-1
for each x in m before middle               --------statement-2
   add x to left
for each x in m after or equal middle       --------statement-3
   add x to right
```

At the `statement-1` you divide the array into two parts and add them to the `left` and `right` sub-array. In the `statement-2`, you are adding all the element before `middle`, which is your middle element of the array. Similarly `statement-3`, you are adding rest of the element in right sub-array. So essentially, you keep on dividing the array in two parts until their size is `1` or `0`.

```
if length(m) <= 1
    return m
```

In the start you have above conditional check, which return the method call if the size of the array is less then or equal to one.

> What then happens on the code below?

```
left = merge_sort(left)
right = merge_sort(right)
```

This is a recursive call to sort (divide the array until size is one) the each sub array. Which is created in the above pseudo-code. You sort `left` and `right` sub-array separately and then join them into a single array.

> return merge(left, right)

Here both `left` and `right` sub-array are passed to a `merge` function. These both array are sorted array. The task of the `merge` function is merge these sub-array into a single sorted array.

Comment: It should be noted that left = merge_sort(left) will keep recursing on left = merge_sort(left), never returning until length(m) <= 1, before it ever gets to the first instance of right = merge_sort(right), which occurs at the next to deepest level of recursion. As mentioned in my answer, this is a depth first, left first, recursion.

Comment: So in the left=merge_sort(left) the process start from top again, just that it divides the 'left' in 2?

Comment: And when the two lists are merged, won't they be divided in two again because length of list is higher than 1?

Comment: no. The `merge` function is getting called after the `merge_sort` function has finished dividing the input into smallest size, which is 1.

Comment: Yes. first half of the array (left) are split into smaller chunk until size is 1. Then right side of the array is processed. Once both these are processed, then merge happens.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo code is missing some details. There was debate on the talk page about removing it or fixing it. Note it's supposed to be working with a list, not an array, which is why elements can only be appended one at a time. The list is not really split into 2 parts; instead two new initially empty lists *left* and *right* are created, then (middle = length/2) elements are moved from *list* to *left*, then (length - middle) elements are moved from *list* to *right*. This cleaned up example with C++ comments may make more sense, but it's still an inefficient way to sort a list. A bottom up merge sort using an array of pointers is much more efficient. I can add example code here if anyone is interested.

```
var list left, right
var integer middle = length(m) / 2
var integer count
for (count = 0; count < middle; count += 1)
     get x from front of list        // x = *list.front()
     remove first element from list  // list.pop_front()
     add x to left                   // left.push_back(x)
for (count = middle; count < length; count += 1)
     get x from front of list        // x = *list.front()
     remove first element from list  // list.pop_front()
     add x to right                  // right.push_back(x)
```

In that same wiki article, there are two C / C++ like code examples, which should be easier to understand. The examples are simplified and copy data back to the original array after each merge step, which could be avoided with more optimized code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation

The sequence is different for top down merge sort, it's depth first, left first:

```
9 6 3 7 5 1 8 2
9 6 3 7|5 1 8 2
9 6|3 7
9|6
6 9
    3|7
    3 7
3 6 7 9
        5 1|8 2
        5|1
        1 5
            8|2
            2 8
        1 2 5 8
1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9
```

Bottom up merge sort skips the recursion and just starts off assuming a run size of 1, and merges width first, left to right:

```
9 6 3 7 5 1 8 2
9|6|3|7|5|1|8|2           run size = 1
6 9|3 7|1 5|2 8           run size = 2
3 6 7 9|1 2 5 8           run size = 4
1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9           done
```

Another example of bottom up merge sort algorithm:

http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/171/Syllabus/7-Sort/merge-sort5.html

Comment: Still I didn't understand much. So studying algorithms with pseudocode is not so smart? (I don't know C, C++ or any other programming language yet).

Comment: @Coder88 - The issue isn't pseudo code, its just that particular wiki example. A bottom up merge sort would be easier to understand, but if you don't know any programming languages, that could make things difficult.

Comment: @Coder88 pseudo code (or an algorithm) is set of sequential logic steps to solve a particular problem. They are always more simple than any programming language code for same. For pseudo is not bound to any particular syntax or anything.