# Mergesort and recursion

Tags: c, recursion, merge, stack, mergesort

So I was going through the code of merge sort and I saw the use of recursion there I did understand that they are using divide and conquer but I am not able to understand how is all this happening(i.e how is the memory getting allocated and arrays dividing inside).It would be great if anyone can explain how the entire process occurs inside the stack with any random memory address(every bit like how much memory the function is allocated and the flow of recursion) images would help a lot.

[image: This image shows the kind of explaination I want with a bit more steps]

P.S-I tried a lot to get some info about it on Google(searched for "working of recursion in merge sort inside stack" and many other things) and tried myself to understand it but couldn't.Thanks in advance for taking time and helping.

Comment: Do You understand what happens on stack when You call a funcion? Regardless of if it is a recursion or not? If You don't, this seems to be a nice tutorial for You: https://manybutfinite.com/post/journey-to-the-stack/

Comment: [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=10&v=XaqR3G_NVoo) gives a great visual representation. Each time the dancers split into a group represents a recursive call.

Comment: @RomanHocke firstly thanks for helping but as I was reading the article I am a bit unfamiliar with some words and things there firstly what is a buffer and what is the f 0 0 thingy in the diagram..

Comment: @Code-Apprentice actually I know how it splits up and how it's arranged what I m unaware of is that how it happens inside the memory....

Comment: @Anonymous286 That video also shows how the arrays are allocated.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that most libraries use some variation of bottom up (iterative) merge sort, and that most instances of top down (recursive) merge sort are for educational purposes.

A typical implementation of top down merge doesn't actually "split" an array, but instead generates indexes that represent the beginning, middle, and end of a sub-array, and effectively pushes those indexes onto the stack when using recursion to call itself. Note that merging does not begin until two base cases of sub-array size == 1 are created, then merging and splitting are done, following the call chain up and down, depth first, left first.

For comparison, a bottom up merge sort doesn't use any recursive steps, and instead starts off by treating an array of n elements as n sub-arrays of size 1, and begins merging even and odd sub-arrays immediately.

The overhead of top down merge sort is not that much, since the recursion has time complexity O(log(n)), while both top down and bottom up merge sort have time complexity O(n log(n)). During the merge steps, eventually the sub-arrays become large enough that most of the time is spent in what is an identical merge function for both top down and bottom up merge sort.

Comment: Thanks for taking time and answering the question,but can you still ellaborate it what I mean to say is with a example and diagram...

Comment: @Anonymous286 - there is example output in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506758/32507027#32507027)